# MSAL v2 Angular - Logout Issue

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular, msal

I am using the @azure/msal-angular version 2 and Angular version 13. The scenario is while calling the logout function the microsoft account signing out the app ( APP A ) successfully. But Ideally other than this app ( APP A ), no other apps which are login already ( Using Microsoft ), should not log out.

( Apps like Microsoft Teams, Outlook, etc... ) These apps are I opened in same browser.

Below code for logout.

```
let accountId  = this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts()[0]?.homeAccountId;

const accountInfoActiveAcc = this.authService.instance.getAccountByHomeId(accountId);

this.authService.logoutPopup({ account: accountInfoActiveAcc });
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update MSAL to V3 and  Try with the mainWindowRedirectUri parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scenario you described, you want to log out from the current  app without logging out other  apps. To do this, you should set the `mainWindowRedirectUri` parameter to the redirect URI of your  app. This will ensure that your  app remains logged in, even though the user has logged out from their Microsoft account.

Here is an example of how to log out from the current  app without logging out other  apps:

In my component.ts updated logout as below

```
logout() {
if (this.msalGuardConfig.interactionType  ===  InteractionType.Popup) {
this.authService.logoutPopup({
mainWindowRedirectUri:  "/"
});
} else {
this.authService.logoutRedirect({
mainWindowRedirectUri:  "/",
});
} 
}
```

**Result**
I opened my Application with Credentials in Localhost
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

After Logout im able to stay logged other Apps

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @saiVamshiKrishna  I opened the teams , outlook  and my angular app in the same browser. After logged out from my angular app. The teams and outlook are logout. It should not happen.

Comment: To prevent Teams and Outlook from logging out when you log out from your Angular app, you can use a single sign-on (SSO) solution that supports multiple sessions. This will allow you to log out from your Angular app without ending the AAD session, so that you can remain logged in to Teams and Outlook.

Hope this reference [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/6982/can-we-restrict-concurrent-logins-of-a-user-in-azu) helps!